# Stop wx richtext from adding Newline

Tags: wxpython, richtextbox

Why does wx.richtext add 'None' from Newline() I'd sure like to get rid of this.

Output:

COMMAS DETECTED IN NAMING!

None

spam and bake beans,spam bake.txt

```
self.bottomview.BeginTextColour((255, 0, 0))                       
gh = str(self.bottomview.WriteText("COMMAS DETECTED IN NAMING!")) + ('\n') + bf
self.bottomview.EndTextColour()
self.bottomview.Newline()
self.bottomview.AppendText(gh)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding 2 new lines: Omit the ('\n')